# Book read in the '80s or '90s about a girl who is kidnapped and replaced, then escapes and returns home to find it different than she remembered

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a book as a kid about a girl who is kidnapped or something and replaced. She eventually escapes and there's a scene where she's riding her bike home but her street looks different...trees look bigger...and she goes home only to see that her parents are older and her replacement is a grown woman. She didn't realize time had passed or something.

Comment: Are there any science fiction or fantasy elements in this story, and if so, can you specify them? For example, is the replacement a clone or a robot or something?

Comment: I can't remember. No one knew she was missing because the replacement was just like her. But maybe less rebellious? Maybe aliens? Eventually she escapes and is surprised by the age of fake her.  It's just been so long and I want to read it again. She was the same age as when she disappeared/replaced. But it had been like 10 years for everyone else. I do not think it was robots.

Comment: I remember that part about her observing the trees looked larger than she remembered and I think as the reader that's when I realized time had passed. Not sure if this helps lol.

Comment: Can't guarantee that we'll find this, but I appreciate the added details.

Comment: Understood and thanks. Fingers crossed.